# SUMO and TraCI, multiple clients - one connection

Tags: python, interface, sumo

I try to access the SUMO Server from to different points, both python scripts. Until now, if i want to get data from my running SUMO, it gives me an ERROR:

`"Received answer 164,0, for command 164,67,car_0"`

(car_0 is a vehicle obviously). I guess it's because it can't connect to the same SUMO.

Short: one running SUMO, multiple python scripts.

Any ideas? I hope it's clear what i want to achieve :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities to achieve this. If you know in advance how many clients will connect (and have sumo 1.0 or later) you can use the multi client functionality starting the server with e.g. `--num-clients 2`. Please note that in this case you need to set the order and every client has to send the simulationStep command, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI. If you have clients connecting dynamically, you will need to use your own proxy where a small wrapper script accepts the connections of your clients and forwards them to sumo.